# Find all solutions to $Bx =[7, -10, 7, 0]^T$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$$ B=\left[
    \begin{array}
        k1 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
        -3 & 2 &-1 & 5\\
        2 & -1 & 1 & 4\\
        0 & 3 & 2 & 4\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I have to find all the solutions of the system $Bx =\left[
    \begin{array}
        k7\\
        -10\\
        7\\
        0\\
    \end{array}
\right]$

What is $Bx$ exactly? Is that just simply the matrix $B$ multiplied by $x$? Therefore:

$$ Bx=\left[
    \begin{array}
        kx & 0 & 2x & x\\
        -3x & 2x &-x & 5x\\
        2x & -x & x & 4x\\
        0 & 3x & 2x & 4x\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

But how can I find all the solutions to this equation? I am clueless as to how to solve this, please help!

Comment: $x$ is most likely meant to be a vector of 4 variables $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. You can solve this equation by Gaussian elimination or if $B$ is invertible find the inverse and multiple the vector on the right by $B^{-1}$.

Comment: Reducing the matrix $[B|c]$ to reduced row echelon form, where $c$ is the column vector $[7,-10,7,0]^{T}$, is the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: find the inverse of **B** and then multiply both sides of the equation Bx = c by such an inverse. This leads to

inv(**B**) **B** **x** = inv(**B**)**c** ,
                 **x** = inv(**B**)**c** .